# What width and height to take while designing Android Apps in Illustrator? Also in what unit like pixels or points…

Tags: android

I want to design an Android app in Illustrator. I read that the Resolution doesn't matter so I will take 72.

But what width and height to take and in pixels or points? Also it would be nice if you can tell how to take it to other resolutions needed for Android.

Thank you.